# Rotate polygon by a numeric value

Tags: qgis, polygon

Is there any way to rotate a polygon or a feature by entering a numeric value in QGIS

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the seventh tool (Select vertex and Object, Rotate Object) of **CAD-Tools** plugin.

An example of use:

1) Selecting feature, rotation point and angle.

[image]

2) After rotation of 45 degrees.

[image]

**CadLayer Polygons** is a memory layer and it can be saved, for example, as shapefile.

**Editing Note:**

I have used this plugin before 2.x QGIS versions where it worked nicely. However, in a newer versions of QGIS, al least in my case, the behavior of  the plugin is not the same as before  where another layer could be selected as rotation center (for example the centroid). However, the centroid could be added as a vertex of a second feature in the original polygon, by using "Split Features" Tool of "Advanced Digitazing Tool Bar" and doing the rotation in two paths; as can be seen below:

[image]

After rotation, you can dissolve the new feature in the rotated polygon.

Comment: This plug-in is no longer able to perform the rotation operation. It always replies "Not enough objects select."

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to comment to Luis, but I just created an account so I can't make any comments. I decided to write this so that no-one thinks that cad-tools doesn't work any more. Cad-tools plugin works well in rotating (Qgis 2.18) but you have to select feature AND vertex (for rotating point) and after that enter angle.